# Calling a public Class in onClick

Tags: java, android

I have an onClick event:

```
   @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mPrayerTime = (Button)findViewById(R.id.muteButton);
    mPrayerTime.setOnClickListener(new  View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //call CityModelHere
        }
    });
```

and I want to call this class (and specifically get the fajr variable without it returning null as it does if I instantiate a new cityModel in the onClick):

```
 public class cityModel implements Serializable {
    private String fajr;



    public void setFajr(String fajr) {
        this.fajr= fajr;

    }
    public String getFajr() {

        return fajr;
    }
}
```

the class takes the string from a later class here just in case:

```
        protected void outputTimings(JSONArray jsonArray) {
        String[] prayers = {"fajr", "shurooq", "dhuhr", "asr", "maghrib", "isha"};
        cityModel cityObj;
        try {
            cityObj= new cityModel();
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject cityObject =
                        jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                result = result + "fajr" + " : "
                        + cityObject.getString("fajr") + "\n" + result + "shurooq" + " : "
                        + cityObject.getString("shurooq") + "\n" + result + "dhuhr" + " : "
                        + cityObject.getString("dhuhr") + "\n" + result + "asr" + " : "
                        + cityObject.getString("asr") + "\n" + result + "maghrib" + " : "
                        + cityObject.getString("maghrib") + "\n" + result + "isha" + " : "
                        + cityObject.getString("isha") + "\n";

                cityObj.setFajr(""+cityObject.getString("fajr"));


            }

        } catch (JSONException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Point of terminology, you don't call classes, you call methods.

Answer (score 0):

Make your variable final, and then you can access it from the setOnClickListener.

Comment: Variable? Do you mean to set the class as final?

Comment: Your cityModel cityObj should be final

Comment: I added final in front of cityModel cityObj; but it still returns null

Comment: can you please help me fix this?

Comment: @Fencer300 I think we are missing something here - when is cityObj  created? Your onClick does not have it (only a comment), so it's hard to see if it was created properly. Please update the whole flow